# Can more than one number be inputted from a switch statement?

Tags: java

I am writing a program that lets the user choose items off a menu, using a switch statement, however when more than one item is chosen I get an exception. My current code is below.

```
    System.out.println("Transaction 1");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Menu"); 
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("(1) Hamburger           $1.99\n(2) Cheeseburger        $2.29\n(3) Chicken Wrap        $3.39\n(4) Chicken Nuggets     $2.29\n(5) Lrg French Fries    $2.49\n(6) Sml French Fries    $1.79\n(7) Bottled Water       $2.19\n(8) Lrg Soda            $1.89\n(9) Sml Soda            $1.49");

    System.out.print("\nPlease type the numbers that correspond to the food you would like to order separated by commas: ");
    toneorder = userInput.nextInt();
    switch (toneorder) {
        case 1: 
            tonefood = "Hamburger";
            break;
        case 2: 
            tonefood = "Cheeseburger";
            break;
        case 3: 
            tonefood = "Chicken Wrap";
            break;
        case 4: 
            tonefood = "Chicken Nuggets";
            break;
        case 5: 
            tonefood = "Lrg French Fries";
            break;
        case 6: 
            tonefood = "Sml French Fries";
            break;
        case 7: 
            tonefood = "Bottled Water";
            break;
        case 8: 
            tonefood = "Lrg Soda";
            break;
        case 9: 
            tonefood = "Sml Soda";
            break;
    }
```

Comment: By "more than one item" do you mean that the user has typed, for example, "12" or "1 2"? You need to parse their input (e.g. split on whitespace characters) or similar.

Comment: What type of exception are you getting? Also, based on the code given, are we to assume that the user will only be prompted to enter an order once yet you're getting an error from them order multiple times?

Comment: I noticed you unmarked my answer as the solution @jdoe12345. Please comment on it why it doesn't work and I will fix it accordingly.

Comment: The error is coming from when they order more than one thing, i.e if I type in "1, 3, 5" for what I want to order I get thrown InputMismatchException instead of having the output be "Hamburger, Chicken Wrap, Lrg French Fries." However if I only order one thing it outputs correctly.

Comment: That is expected. The input should be "1 3 5" not "1, 3, 5" as that will attempt to store a comma in an int variable, which cannot be done. @jdoe12345

Comment: Hm, I tried using your exact code @Spencer4134 and it no longer throws an exception, but the program will not move on to the output, it seems to be stuck in the loop.

Comment: Does it print anything to the screen at all? @jdoe12345 If so, what?

Comment: I found the error and am working on a solution right now. I will be updating my answer with the corrected code.

Comment: @jdoe12345 If you enter a non integer value at the end of the input (i.e. "1 2 3 a") it will run correctly. This value can be literally any character that isn't an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to throw the the whole thing from getting the input, down to the end of the switch statement, into a loop.

```
System.out.print("\nPlease type the numbers that correspond to the food you would like to order separated by spaces: ");

do{
    toneorder = userInput.nextInt();
    switch (toneorder) {
case 1: tonefood = "Hamburger";
    break;
case 2: tonefood = "Cheeseburger";
    break;
case 3: tonefood = "Chicken Wrap";
    break;
case 4: tonefood = "Chicken Nuggets";
    break;
case 5: tonefood = "Lrg French Fries";
    break;
case 6: tonefood = "Sml French Fries";
    break;
case 7: tonefood = "Bottled Water";
    break;
case 8: tonefood = "Lrg Soda";
    break;
case 9: tonefood = "Sml Soda";
    break;
}while (userInput.hasNextInt());
```

You will also want to change `tonefood = /*item*/` to `tonefood += /*item*/ + " ";` if you want to store all the selected options in the variable 'tonefood'.

Also, don't prompt the user to separate the input with commas. Have them separated by spaces to automatically get the next numbers, as a comma cannot be stored in an int variable. So say you want to input the numbers 1, 2, and 3. The input should be `1 2 3` and not `1, 2, 3` or `1,2,3`.

The user will need to enter a non-integer value after the input to terminate the input. Something like `1 2 3 buy` or `checkout` will work if you want to prompt the user for that.

Hope this helps!